# Get all button elements with xpath condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xpath, queryselector

I am currently trying to get all button elements using `document.querySelectorAll('button')` which contains the class `btn primary-button`

So, my new snippet is `document.querySelectorAll("button//contains(@class,'btn primary-button')")`  but this is throwing error as

```
querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'button//contains(@class,'btn primary-button')' 
is not a valid selector
```

Please suggest how to fix this

Comment: I am trying to run above snippet in browser console which contains a certain class

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.primary-button")`

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Parameters) - querySelector does not take an xpath

Answer (score 0):

I think querySelector uses selector instead of xpath.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.btn.primary-button')
```

Comment: As I already commented. The question should really be closed